# C# - How to create temporary value that does not change original value

Tags: c#, variables, temp

I have the following code:

```
Field[,] tempSudoku = Sudoku;
```

now if I do:

```
Sudoku[row, col].Domain.Remove(5);
```

this also removes 5 from the domain of `tempSudoku`. I want this to not happen, I need `tempSudoku` to be my backup `Sudoku`. What I'd like to see is that the domain of `Sudoku` is reduced by **{5}**, but the domain of `tempSudoku` stays the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to clone it like : `Field[,] tempSudoku = (Field[,]Sudoku.Clone());`

Comment: Id suggest you to revise how variables works... especially with objects, When you're doing : tempSudoku = Sudoku you're copying a reference to Soduku, so if Soduku changes, tempSoduku does as well. You need to clone it: `Field[,] tempSudoku = (Field[,]Sudoku.Clone());`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, however this code does not compile?

Comment: @Hevol you have to write `.Clone()` yourself and add it to the method, it does not get created automatically.

Comment: Note that you can clone the array itself as @Ehsan suggests, but this won't solve your problem (even after you fix the syntax error in Ehsan's comment), because you seem to want the `Domain` objects cloned as well. See marked duplicate for information about performing a "deep clone" on the array. You need to copy not just the array, but make copies of each object within as well.